# Print RDLC report without showing PrintDialog() in web application in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, printdocument

How to print the content of RDLC report directly by clicking one button without showing preview using client's default printer in asp.net with C#/VB (page size will be same as report's page size and this question is for web application)

I did a try to solve it but i don't know how to print by printer at client side.
 1. I take content of report viewer and make a PDF from it and save it.
    There is a button and a report viewer:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string savePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "PDF\\Report" + Default.reportNumber + ".pdf";
        Default.reportNumber ++;

        if (!File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "PDF\\Report1.pdf"))
        {
            Default.reportNumber = 2;
            savePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "PDF\\Report1.pdf";
        }

        SavePDF(ReportViewer1, savePath);
        PrintPDF(savePath);

        File.Delete(savePath);
    }

    public void SavePDF(ReportViewer viewer, string savePath)
    {
        byte[] Bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render(format: "PDF", deviceInfo: "");

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

2. Now what i put in function PrintPDF()?

   ```
   private void PrintPDF(string savePath)
   {
       //....?....
   }
   ```

Comment: the page size can be customized, like we can set page width and height for ex. 4x2

Comment: question is for web application asp.net is specified. in web application any client can click on print button and content will be given to client's default printer and page size will be same as specified in rdlc report(ex, 4x2)